# discord Oauth2 access token undefined

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, discord

So i am trying to create a discord bot dashboard and I am including a Discord Oauth2 to get User information. My Discord Oauth2 works, however after authorising, it redirects me to the homepage but the URL has token=undefined . The console does log "It works!". How do I fix the undefined access token?

`http://localhost:3000/?token=undefined`

```
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const btoa = require('btoa');
const { catchAsync } = require('./utils.js')

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const redirect = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/callback');

...

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${redirect}&response_type=code&scope=identify%20email%20guilds`);
  });

app.get('/callback', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.query.code) throw new Error('NoCodeProvided');
    const code = req.query.code;
    const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);
    const response = await fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirect}`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
        },
      });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log("it works!")
    res.redirect(`/?token=${json.access_token}`);
  }));
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: `fetch` always resolve any data received even if it's an 404 or 500, in order to check if there's any error, you have to add `if (!response.ok) { // log error... }`. AFAIK, `/token` doesn't allow GET queries, have you tried putting your data to the body?

Comment: @HoangDao It seems that there was a problem with how the request was sent, So I changed the format and saved the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri, code, etc to a variable and sent it as a URLSearchParams and now it works

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a problem with how the callback link was set up, So I changed it to look like this and it works.

```
app.get('/callback', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

    const data = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirect,
        code: req.query.code,
        scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
    };
    
    const response = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams(data),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    })

    const json = await response.json();

    const fetchDiscordUserInfo = await fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${json.access_token}`,
  }
});
const userInfo = await fetchDiscordUserInfo.json();

    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/dashboard')

console.log(userInfo);
```